# Windows Service Installation using Command Prompt

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

The only way to install `windows-service` I know is using "**Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt**", Is there a way to install windows-service on a machine which isn't having *Visual Studio* installed (assume that `.Net` version 4.X is installed)?

Comment: Find `installutil` in the appropriate (correct version) .Net directory. For example: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

Answer (score 0):

Call to SDK Command prompt, follow

```
Start>All Programs>Microsoft .NET Framework SDK v2.0>SDK Command prompt
```

Type in the SDK command prompt

```
installutil C:\MyWebServiceApp\bin\Debug\MyService.exe
```

this is your application's .exe path.

Now your Windows service has successfully installed with Windows Environment.

To start that, go to

```
Start>Run type services.msc and run it.
```

In this services window, find your Windows Service and Write Click on it and select Properties. Set Startup type as Automatic or Manual.

Now restart you machine and find your Windows Service by Task Manager. It will display in task manager under running services.

[Reference here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/52471/Install-Windows-Service)

Answer (score 0):

Try   `installutil <Path of the Service>`

---

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`

Comment: I am Try This Code on Command Prompt    C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe D:\Service Test\TestServices\RollsManiaService\bin\Debug>RollsManiaService.exe                                                                                                        They Show The Following Error

Answer (score 0):

you can use batch file and call it from your installer or application

For Installation

```
@ECHO OFF

REM The following directory is for .NET 4.0
set DOTNETFX4=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNETFX4%

echo Installing WindowsService...
echo ---------------------------------------------------
InstallUtil /i YouServiceName.exe
echo ---------------------------------------------------
echo Done.
```

For Uninstall

```
@ECHO OFF

REM The following directory is for .NET 4.0
set DOTNETFX4=%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
set PATH=%PATH%;%DOTNETFX4%

echo Installing WindowsService...
echo ---------------------------------------------------
InstallUtil /u YouServiceName.exe
echo ---------------------------------------------------
echo Done.
```